# Recursion in react component that generates a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, recursion

## Hi there SO!

I'm currently trying to make a form that generates based on the object supplied and this seem to work at just about anything I throw at it. 

That is, until I get to a nested object.

---

###### The problem:

Once I hit the if condition `(typeof value === "object")` I want to have a hidden input (this works). 
Then I want to go into that object I just identified, and into all child objects it may contain and generate the input on same criteria as the initial run-through.

```
function GenericForm(props: any) {
  var object = props.object;

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {Object.entries(object).map(([property, value]) => {
          let type: string = "";
          if (typeof value === "string") {
            type = "text";
          } else if (typeof value === "number") {
            type = "number";
          } else if (typeof value === "boolean") {
            type = "checkbox";
          } else if (value instanceof Date) {
            type = "date";
          } else if (typeof value === "object") {
            type = "hidden";
          }

          return [
            <label property={property} htmlFor={property}>
              {property}
            </label>,
            <input
              type={type}
              id={property}
              name={property}
              defaultValue={value as string}
              onChange={(newVal) => {
                object[property] = newVal.target.value;
              }}
            />,
          ];
        })}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default GenericForm;
```

I'm aware that this most likely utilizes some kind of recursion and while I have tried to solve it using recursion, I haven't been able to solve it. 
 the code pasted here is from before I tried recursion, to have a "clean sheet" from where it went wrong for me.

### EDIT 1 - added info on object structure

the object passed should be completely generic and allow for objects of any structure to be handed to the component, currently it should then just evaluate what type the properties are and make an input element from that.

one of the current objects I'm passing have the following JSON Schema

```
{
    "id": "XYZ1",
    "type": "twilio-api",
    "sid": "someSID",
    "from": "+phonenumberhere",
    "name": "TWILIO SMS",
    "credentials": {
        "token": "someapitoken"
    }
}
```

above object currently renders like so:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to also share what `object` looks like (along with the expected output for it)?

Comment: Please don't add a lot of distracting **boldface** and *italics* to your post, and please do use proper capitalization and spelling. Both of those make it easier to read your question and help you. Also, SO's community standards strongly discourage "fluff" in questions, like salutations and thank yous.

Comment: @NickParsons added an edit to the post about the object schema.
the expected output would be an credentials label with hidden input, and then underneath the token with its input defined by type like the previous have been, this should go to the end of the object structure not limited to the "2 level" objects in the linked object

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as English isn't my native language, i am sorry for whatever misspellings I'm making, i do use my autocorrection to fix before posting, so i hope it isn't too bad.
gotcha on the fluff, i'll update my post accordingly :)

Comment: @robskaar - :-) I guarantee you that you write English better than I write any other language. One thing that really jumps out though to native speakers is that "I" is always capitalized, never lower case (not "i"). Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a `Input` component:

```
  function Input = ({ name, type, value }) => {
    // most of your code can fit here
    return <input name={name} type={type} value={value} />
  }
```

You can use your version of code, I use a simplified version as above to make our discussion easier. With that we can design a `InputList` component:

```
  function InputList = ({ object }) => {
    console.log('list', object)
    return (
      <div>
        {Object.entries(object).map(([property, value]) => {
           if (typeof value === "object") {
             return <InputList object={value} />
           } else {
             return <Input name={property} />
           }
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

You can see inside this `InputList`, there's a call to `InputList` again, so that is the recursion you are looking for. The recursion stops when you don't have an object inside an object any more.

NOTE: *React* requires `value` and `onChange` to drive any `input` box. Otherwise they'll just behave like a native input. But this is not part of this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems almost too simple and yet so obvious that i just return another component if the condition is met.
I'm just leaving work now. will try this out sometime tomorrow, if it fixes the issue I'll of course mark it as an answer, in the meantime I've upvoted your suggestion as it already seems intuitive :)

Comment: Not a problem @robskaar, there's couple of different ways to do recursion. In  the more textbook version, we would only design one component called `Input`, but i found it too messy when it comes to the testing. It's better we can see each simple input works and then the list of inputs works, one step at a time.

Comment: I had to do a little tweaking, but it ended up working perfectly. simple and intuitive solution but i had my head was fixated within trying to make it a recursive function above the return of the component and implement it within the components return section, so i didn't even consider this solution of moving it out and just calling the component when condition was met.
still i had to tweak it a bit, but ultimately this ended up solving the most parts of the issue, and i now have a generic form that i can toss any object at. 
thanks for your help !